# windows phone 8 app Application_Activated() never called

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am writing a windows phone 8 app.

I just realized that everytime I switch to the app (no matter if it's the first time or it's after I hit HOME then hit the app tile to come back), Application_Launching() is called. Application_Activated(), on the other hand, never gets called.

Wondering if I'm doing anything wrong.

```
    // Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
    // This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.AppLaunch();
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
    // This code will not execute when the application is first launched
    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.AppActive();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected - you are always launching a fresh instance of your app by tapping the app tile in the Start screen.

After you press the HOME key, you have to hit the hardware back key if you want to test the `Application_Activated` method. If you hold down a long time on the hardware back key you should get a list of recent apps you can go back into in this way.

Comment: Indeed, pressing the app tile results in fresh start, while hitting back key results in re-activation. Thanks a lot.